# What does it mean by saying "You are my eyes and ears"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

I have heard "**You are my eyes and ears**" in some movies, but can not see its definition on the internet.

Sometimes they say "**my eyes and ears** are everywhere"

SO, I guess "**my eyes and ears** are people who work for me and collect and tell all important information that I need.

What does it mean by saying "**You are my eyes and ears**"?

Answer (score 2):

You are substantially correct.

“You are my eyes and ears” implies two things, a person who trustworthily reports information to you, AND the implication that you are either physically absent  from the scene where the facts of interest reside, or are being purposefully deceived by the concealment of facts.

It is not necessary that the trusty reporter work or report to you in a job or hierarchical sense.   And note that there exists the possibility that the reporter herself can double cross, or act as a double agent with respect to the principal.

Comment: purposefully - deliberately? principal - principle? Or are these US usages?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Principal == prime character, hero, protagonist, person who has these aforementioned 'spies'.